# how to solve Error installing whisper-mic: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper_mic.utils'

Tags: package, modulenotfounderror, openai-whisper, whisper

tried following this video of how to install whisper-mic https://youtu.be/S58MGCU7Wgg?si=YPMc1a35NNq3ppiK
it's as simple as running a virtual env and the pip install whisper-py.
it gives me errors like
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement whisper-mic
ERROR: No matching distribution found for whisper-mic
line 13, in 
from whisper_mic.utils import get_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whisper_mic.utils'; 'whisper_mic' is not a package

I tried creating conda env and venv but still same issues.
also tried python 3.8 and 3.9.9 still no change.